# Which are the Euler and Runge-Kutta odometry formulas for a four mecanum wheels omnidirectional robot?

Tags: odometry

I have a omnidirectional robot with four mecanum wheels and I have computed its linear and angular velocities starting from wheel speeds expressed in ticks. Now, to compute odometry, I have to integrate with Euler and Runge-Kutta methods, but I can't find the formulas for this type of robot. Which ones can I use?